# OpenGL or other image processing in the browser, without canvas?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to make a program similar to after effects or blender in the browser, in the sense of developing certain animations etc., and compiling the animations and keyframes info a video, preferably frame-by-frame

Using the built in methods of the canvas and media recorder, I have yet to find a way to process a video by inserting one frame at a time, to a set framerate, usually the media recorder just records live in real time, it doesn't seem to be meant for frame by frame rendering, and also the canvas is limited in the sense of being too slow or unreliable to consistently get the image from it using either toDataURL or glGetPixels etc.

Is there a way to process videos in JavaScript without using the canvas at all?

Meaning, instead it would just generate the image data and display it as an img tag, or even a real time low quality video encoding and streaming, on the client side, and attach the stream to a video tag somehow, or perhaps the canvas could be used for development of the keyframes etc. but the actual processing would be done by scratch, is this the best way to go about this? And if so, how can it be done?

Comment: You're trying to do native-type functionality in the browser. Canvas and media recorder are as good as it gets in HTML, I'm afraid. Maybe someone else has a better idea, but I think you'd have to do this using Web Assembly rather than HTML/JS.

Comment: @see interesting, would it be possible to do OpenGL image processing with web assembly only? Has anything like it every been tried?

Comment: To get a video, you basically need to feed images(frames) to a video encoder. Unfortunately, it is not exposed as an API in browsers. A while ago I was able to run [open264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) decoder via WebAssembly, but the performance was not good enough to build a video player around it. I did not try the encoding though, so I am not sure.